# Match referer by regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I'd like to setup a simple notification if a view has a specific base referer.

Let's say I land on `http://myapp.com/page/` and I came from `http://myapp.com/other/page/1`. Here's an example of my pseudo code, basically if I'm coming from any page/X I want to setup a notification.

I'm thinking it might be something like `^r^myapp.com/other/page/$` but I'm not so familiar with how to use regex with python.

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
def someview(request): 
     notify = False
     ... # other stuff not important to question
     req = HttpRequest()
     test = req.META['HTTP_REFERER'] like "http://myapp.com/other/page*"
     # where * denotes matching anything past that point and the test returns T/F
     if test:
        notify = True

    return # doesn't matter here
```

This may be more of a "how do I use regex in this context" rather than a django question specifically.

Comment: By the way - since you pointed out the return doesn't matter... actually it is pretty important in web applications. If you don't return at the end of your planned control flow (e.g.: failed authentication) but just perform a redirect, you can expose yourself to undesired effects :-)

Comment: Yes, I just meant that what comes after return '...' doesn't matter here. ie, it's not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with something like this:

```
import re
referrer = "http://myapp.com/other/page/aaa"
m = re.match("^http://myapp.com/other/page/(.*)", referrer)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```